# Error: Failed to connect before the deadline when firing transactions at high rate

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to perform performance testing on Hyperledger Fabric v1.2. Network is setup, using fabcar chaincode. Transactions arrival rate in 50 RPS. Using Node JS application to accept transaction requests. Transactions perform putState operation, by adding new variable in the ledger, using [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/fabcar/invoke.js) code.

- Consensus Used: Solo
- Number of Nodes: 4 (orderer and all peers are on
  different virtual machines)
- Ledger: CouchDB

At lower RPS (0-20), all the transactions are successfully passing. On increasing the transaction arrival rate to 50, around 50% of total transactions fail with the error

```
Transaction proposal was good
Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - 200, message - ""
error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
error: [Orderer.js]: Orderer grpc://x.x.x.x:7050 has an error Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 
Failed to connect before the deadline
```

What does this error mean actually? Why is the client unable to send endorsed transaction to the orderer? 
And around 20% of them failed with the following error

```
Send transaction promise and event listener promise have completed in 30086 ms
Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.
Transaction failed to be committed to the ledger due to ::TIMEOUT
```

As per different research papers, Hyperledger Fabric must be able to process requests at rates as high as 2000, why is it giving such results?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem by using the invoke code from fabric-samples repository. I fixed the issue by changing the order of promise chaining.

What I did was as follows:

```
return checkUser(this.user)
.then(() => return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request))
.then((results) => checkPrposal(results))
.then((results) => submitTrasaction(results))
.then(() => connectEventHub())
```